Why does this empty "for" loop affect this program's result?
At the beginning, I tried:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){  
    int a,b,i;
    scanf("%c",&a);  
    if (a<=122 && a>=97)  
        a=a-32;  
    b=a-64;  
    printf("%d",b);  
    return 0;
}

and it works well. However, when I tried this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){  
    int a,b,i;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if (a<=122 && a>=97)  
        a=a-32;  
    b=a-64;  
    printf("%d",b);

    for(i=1;i <= 5;i++){
        ;   
    }
    
    return 0;
}

it showed a strange answer. In the test, when I type 'A', the program 1 showed "1", but the program 2 showed "32557" or something.
I have already known that the type of a should have been char. After I corrected it, it did work. However, I was still wondering why this issue occurred.

Using the wrong format specifier with scanf (like using %c instead of %d for reading an int) results in undefined behaviour (google that term), which basically means "anything can happen".


and it works well

It actually doesn't. If you enable all warnings (see What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?), then you'll get something like:

warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int *'

Using the wrong format specifier for scanf, in this case %c when you are passing it an int, is undefined behavior. Meaning a bug which can cause anything to happen.
Unfortunately the bug remained dormant the first time you ran the program. But suddenly surfaced when you did some completely unrelated changes. Such is the nature of undefined behavior bugs - anything can happen - including "seems to work fine for now".
What is undefined behavior and how does it work?

"when you are passing it an int" better as "when you are passing it an int *".

variable 'i' affects the location of other variable in stack. disassemble would show the difference

int main(){
    1189:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    118d:       55                      push   %rbp
    118e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1191:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    1195:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    119c:       00 00
    119e:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    11a2:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    int a,b,i;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    11a4:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
    11a8:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    11ab:       48 8d 05 52 0e 00 00    lea    0xe52(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    11b2:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11b5:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    11ba:       e8 d1 fe ff ff          call   1090 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>

int main(){
    1189:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    118d:       55                      push   %rbp
    118e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1191:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    1195:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    119c:       00 00
    119e:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    11a2:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    int a,b,i;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    11a4:       48 8d 45 ec             lea    -0x14(%rbp),%rax
    11a8:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    11ab:       48 8d 05 52 0e 00 00    lea    0xe52(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    11b2:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    11b5:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    11ba:       e8 d1 fe ff ff          call   1090 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>


This answer is probably beyond the scope of the OP...

The answer doesn't really explain the actual issue here which is UB (undefined-behavior) due to invalid format specifier with scanf.
